# Cant call mongodb methods from a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, function, database

So i made a user login, the database is mongodb and it works perfect. However, i want to to call the mongodb again after the person logins in, so i decided to split it up into separate functions. However, when i tried taking the login script and turn in into a function, the database wont open. Which makes no sense, since im using the exact same code that worked inside the route. Can this be done in a function? Does anyone know what’s going on?

Below is the code and images of the debugger proving the dB wont open.

Route

```
   // Listen for Upload file 
    router.post('/uploadFile', function (req, res) {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error uploading file");
            } else {
                //var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
                var username = req.body.username ; 
                var fileName = req.file.filename ; 
                var filePath = req.file.path ; 
                console.log(username);
                console.log("GET " + req.file.fieldname);
                console.log("GET " + req.file.filename);
                console.log("GET " + req.file.orignalName);
                console.log("GET " + req.file.path);
                var result = findOne(username); 
                res.json(result); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Function call

```
function findOne(username){
    var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        console.log(databaseName + ": opened");
        console.log(db);
        db.collection(collection).findOne({username:username}, function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            if (doc != null) {
                console.log("Found");
                // db.close();
                return "Found" ; 

            } else {
                console.log("Not Found");
                // db.close();
                return "Not found";
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
console.log("Did not open")
db.close(); 
return 0 ; // Should not be called
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you trim your code and post only the relevant snippets?

Comment: i sense a race condition issue.   when findOne gets called, it will take time to open the db, look up the record and respond.  it's possible res.json() triggers before that completes.  have you commented out res.json() just to see if logs are written out when the DB is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what ES version you're running but if you want to take the synchronous approach, try this version of findOne.  Async/Await makes asynch code synchronous.

```
async function findOne(username){
    var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));

    let db = await db.open();
    // try above line first
    //let {err, db} = await db.open();

    let doc = await db.collection(collection).findOne({username:username});
    // try above line first
    //let {err, doc} = await db.collection(collection).findOne({username:username});

    //assert.equal(null, err);
    if (doc != null) {
        console.log("Found");
        // db.close();
        return "Found" ; 

    } else {
        console.log("Not Found");
        // db.close();
        return "Not found";
    }
    db.close();

//console.log("Did not open")
//db.close(); 
//return 0 ; // Should not be called
}
```

If you get an error for Async/Await, try installing this package.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code as observed on first look.

1. Use of return in asynchronous functions to return a result will not work.
   You need to define a callback function which you pass as reference to findOne. This callback function needs to be called to return the result.
2. Printing of "Did not open" in this scenario does not mean Database did not open. This is asynchronous execution so database may open after printing of that console log.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the typical asynchronous callback problem that most newly introduced JavaScript developers experience.

First of all, [JavaScript is asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) (Must read for you). That means that when you pass a function as a parameter of something, you can't expect that the code inside the function will run inline to the code. Maybe the function that you pass will be called as a result of an event (connect to something, user clicked a button, a database is opened...), so will happen sometime in the future. Even if is 1 nanosecond after, will be in the future.

So you expect it to run this way:

```
function findOne(username){
    // Start with this (step 1)
    var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
    // Then continue with this (step 2)
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
    // Open the database (step 3) and the code will wait for the database to open
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        // Run this inline, just after db.open (step 4)
        console.log("OPEN");
        [...]
    });
    // Continue with this after the database was open (step 5)
    console.log("Did not open")
    db.close(); 
    return 0 ; // Should not be called
}
```

But actually what is happening is this:

```
function findOne(username){
    // Start with this (step 1)
    var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
    // Then continue with this (step 2)
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
    // Open the database (step 3), pass a function that will be called by the database when is open AND continue with the next step
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        // This function will be called when the database is open, so right now is not called.
        console.log("OPEN");
        [...]
    });
    // This is the next step after step 3 (step 4).
    console.log("Did not open")
    db.close(); 
    return 0 ; // Should not be called
}

// And sometime in the future you suddenly get in console OPEN, when the database decides to run the callback you passed to it.
```

Another way to look into this is that a `return` will always return from a function, so having this nested function:

```
function findOne(username) { // function keyword, so this is a function (number 1)
    [...]
    db.open(function (err, db) { // Note the function keyword here, so this is a function too (number 2)
        [...]
        return 1; // This return actually works, BUT affects the function where it belongs, which is function number 2 in this case.
    });
    [...]
    return 0; // And this one is the return of the function number 1.
}
```

So imagine that `db.open` runs the callback immediately, before running the very next line of code. Although it is not ran in an asynchronous way, the `return` inside the callback still can't return the `findOne` function.

Async problems require async solutions. (Or use ES6 generators (async, await, etc...), but currently will complicate you more as you won't still understand what is happening with your code, and worse, when to use generators (as they are tied to async callbacks), so better first understand async callbacks in JS). When you understand it, is pretty easy actually. Just a few changes:

```
// Listen for Upload file
router.post('/uploadFile', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading file");
        } else {
            //var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
            var username = req.body.username ; 
            var fileName = req.file.filename ; 
            var filePath = req.file.path ; 
            console.log(username);
            console.log("GET " + req.file.fieldname);
            console.log("GET " + req.file.filename);
            console.log("GET " + req.file.orignalName);
            console.log("GET " + req.file.path);
            // Converted the sync function to an async one, by passing a
            // callback function as a parameter with 2 arguments, being
            // the first the possible error and the second the data
            findOne(username, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error uploading file");
                } else {
                    res.json(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

// Here you can see now that we have the callback parameter,
// that references the callback function we passed before and
// we can call it whenever we want
function findOne(username, callback) {
    var databaseName = "E-learn", collection = "Accounts";
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err); // If error, pass the error as first argument of the callback
        } else {
            console.log(databaseName + ": opened");
            console.log(db);
            db.collection(collection).findOne({username:username}, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err); // As findOne is another async callback too, the same as above. Check for err
                } else {
                    // And if everything is fine, then pass the result as the second parameter of the callback
                    if (doc != null) {
                        callback(null, "Found");
                    } else {
                        callback(null, "Not found");
                    }
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As you may have noticed, you pass a lot of `function` as callbacks, in the database methods and inside the router methods too.

And some developer protips:

- Now simply read the code line by line and try to understand what is happening on each one. This way you may wondered "Why the code I've not written is made by callbacks and mine not?". This question and a bit of research will helped you a lot.
- Always have clean indentation. Your code have some problems with it. Indentation is a must in JavaScript where you can have a callback hell because of his asynchronous nature, and indentation helps a lot with it.